# C++ Set Comparator Data Structure

Tags: c++, algorithm, set, comparator

I am using a C++ STL set with a custom comparator to store an Edge data structure as shown below.  I defined the Edge to be essentially a key-value pair.  Index is the key and I want to iterate through the collection by value (maxlength) from largest to smallest.  At any given time, I usually only care about the edges with the 3 largest values.  There will only be a relatively small number of edges in the collection ranging from around 7 to 64.  When I insert an edge, the values of the two adjacent edges will need to be adjusted.  To do this, I will add the new edge to the set, then remove the two adjacent edges and re-add them with their new values.  Can anyone share a more efficient data structure for this purpose?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct Edge {
    int maxlength;
    int index;

    Edge(int index, int maxlength) {
        this->maxlength = maxlength;
        this->index = index;
    }

    bool operator<(Edge other) const {
        return maxlength < other.maxlength;
    }
};

void run() {
    set<Edge> edges;
    edges.insert(Edge(25, 3));
    edges.insert(Edge(21, 4));
    edges.insert(Edge(28, 2));

    cout << "First Edge: " << edges.begin()->maxlength << endl;
    edges.erase(Edge(28, 2));
    cout << "First Edge: " << edges.begin()->maxlength << endl;
    edges.insert(Edge(39, 1));
    cout << "First Edge: " << edges.begin()->maxlength << endl;
    cout << "Last Edge: " << (--edges.end())->maxlength << endl;
}

int main() {
    run();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Ask questions about problems, not your attempted solutions. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378 What's actual problem you need to solve by this?

Comment: If your problem 'size' is not large and your present code works, why do you need a more efficient data structure?